# Moving merged XAML ResourceDictionaries to Generic.xaml causes error

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have created two custom controls, both inherited from System.Windows.Controls.Button. One is called `XLButton` and the other is `XLBox`. They have identical XAML styles/templates in two separate `ResourceDictionary` objects in two separate .xaml files, and identical code-behind files, except that "XLButton" appears in the `XLButton` files where "XLBox" appears in the `XLBox` files, and *vice versa*.

I have created a simple test window with a two-row `Grid`. I merge the the `ResourceDictionary` files into a the `Window.Resources` of that test window and create an instance of each custom control, one in the top row, one in the bottom. This works fine. Here's the test window's XAML:

```xml
<Window x:Class="ScratchPadWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ExLuminaControls"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="ScratchPadWindow" Height="118" Width="145">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/XLBox.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/XLButton.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <local:XLBox Content="Hi!"/>
        <local:XLButton Grid.Row="1" Content="Yeah!"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This works just fine. But, when I comment out the `ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries` section and copy it in its original form to `Themes\Generic.xaml`, so it looks like this:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ExLuminaControls"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/XLButton.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/XLBox.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I get a "Cannot locate resource 'styles/xlbutton.xaml' error, associated with this line:

```xml
<local:XLBox Content="Hi!"/>
```

That doesn't make sense to me, but what's more confusing is that *the problem goes away if i click "Disable project code" in the designer*.

I'm using Blend 2017 Community.

Can anyone help me understand this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's path problem, when in generic, use it like this

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="/AssemblyName;Component/Styles/XLButton.xaml" />
```

or have to go up with "../../"

1. themes and generic lowercase
2. assembly info
3. app.xaml if nothing works

   [assembly: ThemeInfo(
   ResourceDictionaryLocation.None, //where theme specific resource dictionaries are located
   //(used if a resource is not found in the page, 
   // or application resource dictionaries)
   ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly //where the generic resource dictionary is located
   //(used if a resource is not found in the page, 
   // app, or any theme specific resource dictionaries)
   )]

   ```
   <ResourceDictionary>
       <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

           <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Fluent;Component/Themes/Generic.xaml" />
           ...
       </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
   </ResourceDictionary>
   ```

Definition and style

```
#region --------------------CONSTRUCTORS--------------------

    static WaitSpin()
    {
        FrameworkElement.DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(WaitSpin),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(WaitSpin)));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// LoadingAnimation constructor.
    /// </summary>
    public WaitSpin()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(WaitSpin);
    }

    #endregion


<Style x:Key="{x:Type local:WaitSpin}" TargetType="{x:Type local:WaitSpin}">
```

Comment: I'm afraid that makes no difference. It still works when I put the `ResourceDictionary` reference in the `Window`'s .xaml file, but not when I put it (either with or without the `/ExLuminaControls;Component` part of the path) in the `generic.xaml` file.

Comment: Ok, 3 others to check, see above

Comment: Thanks. Your path did fix the ref when I moved from Blend to VS. All those other things check out fine. The problem is, apparently, subtler than I thought.The custom Style still has no effect when defined in generic.xaml. If I move the Style definition into the generic.xaml file directly, it still has no effect. But, if I make a second project, identical to the first except for its name, the second project can instantiate the custom control from the first project and the style in generic.xaml is applied. No idea why generic.xaml doesn't apply in its own project. Marking your answer correct.

Comment: i updated; also take care about the style and control definition

Comment: It looks like you've got generic.xaml merging itself. Is that what you meant to do?

Comment: heu, not really, have a look in this repo : https://github.com/TheCamel/CBR/tree/master/CBR